# "ERROR: zlib check failed" while compiling Qemu

Tags: compiling, qemu

I recently formatted my PC and reinstalled Ubuntu 13.04 via Wubi in Windows.

And after updates I'm getting this error:

```
basel@ubuntu:~/Desktop/qemu-1.6-test$ ./configure --cross-prefix=i586-mingw32msvc- --prefix=/home/basel/Desktop/qemu-1.6-test

ERROR: zlib check failed
       Make sure to have the zlib libs and headers installed.
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 8):

You don't have the headers/libraries to build qemu. The easy way to solve this situation is doing:

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends -y build-dep qemu
```

Now, to solve that message:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: Just curious... why did you say "--no-install-recommends"?

Comment: @Phani The one that actually solves the problem (error message) is the second one. The first is to prepare a minimal build environment for building qemu.

Comment: I get that. but I am curious why you did not consider the recommended packages. Is there usually no added value in installing such recommended packages?

Comment: @Phani the build-dep command should pull all the build dependencies already. There isn't any significant gain of installing more than necessary, making apt to install recommended packages of the build dependencies themself.