# Error trying to compile qemu from source

Tags: 12.10, qemu

I am trying to compile qemu from source to get my hands dirty with its development. I cloned the package from [the repository](http://git.qemu-project.org/?p=qemu.git;a=snapshot;h=refs/heads/master;sf=tgz). I extracted the tarball and started with the configuration using

```
./configure
```

when I got the following error:

```
ERROR: DTC (libfdt) not present. Your options:
         (1) Preferred: Install the DTC (libfdt) devel package
         (2) Fetch the DTC submodule, using:
             git submodule update --init dtc
```

I tried installing libfdt using `sudo apt-get install libfdt-dev` but this did not resolve the error.

There is a similar question I have seen but this too could not solve the error I am facing:

- [“ERROR: zlib check failed” while compiling Qemu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335875/error-zlib-check-failed-while-compiling-qemu)

How do I fix this error to successfully compile qemu from source?

**Edit:**

Executing `git submodule update --init dtc` while I am still in the qemu package's directory returned the following error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

Comment: did you run "git submodule update --init dtc"

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Ran the command but got an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fix this issue:

- Cloned dtc from [its repository](http://git.qemu-project.org/?p=dtc.git;a=snapshot;h=1760e7ca03894689118646e229ca9487158cd0e8;sf=tgz) and extract the tarball to `qemu/dtc/`.
- Compile dtc from source using `make`
- Restart configuring qemu using `./configure` when in `qemu` directory.

The problem was qemu tries to search for dtc binaries in `qemu/dtc`. Even if you have installed dtc using `sudo apt-get install device-tree-compiler`, you will get the above error(mentioned in the question), so you probably need to have the binaries in `qemu/dtc`.

Answer (score 6):

From the error:

```
ERROR: DTC (libfdt) not present. Your options:
     (1) Preferred: Install the DTC (libfdt) devel package
     (2) Fetch the DTC submodule, using:
         git submodule update --init dtc
```

See item (2): use git submodule update --init dtc

Try get the qemu source code from the git:

```
# git clone git://git.qemu.org/qemu.git
# cd qemu
# git submodule init
# git submodule update --recursive
# git submodule status --recursive
65cc4d2748a2c2e6f27f1cf39e07a5dbabd80ebf dtc (v1.4.0)
87eea99e443b389c978cf37efc52788bf03a0ee0 pixman (pixman-0.32.6)
b4c93802a5b2c72f096649c497ec9ff5708e4456 roms/SLOF (qemu-slof-20141202-63-gb4c9380)
4e03af8ec2d497e725566a91fd5c19dd604c18a6 roms/ipxe (v1.0.0-2016-g4e03af8)
3caee1794ac3f742315823d8447d21f33ce019e9 roms/openbios (3caee17)
c559da7c8eec5e45ef1f67978827af6f0b9546f5 roms/openhackware (heads/master)
c87a92639b28ac42bc8f6c67443543b405dc479b roms/qemu-palcode (heads/master)
33fbe13a3e2a01e0ba1087a8feed801a0451db21 roms/seabios (rel-1.8.2)
23d474943dcd55d0550a3d20b3d30e9040a4f15b roms/sgabios (heads/master)
2072e7262965bb48d7fffb1e283101e6ed8b21a8 roms/u-boot (v2014.07-rc1-79-g2072e72)
19ea12c230ded95928ecaef0db47a82231c2e485 roms/vgabios (heads/master)
```

And after it you can call ./configure.

Comment: Sorry deleting comment. My case was special.